# position sticky failing to stick after threshold

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to use `sticky` positioning on one of my elements, but for some reason even if I cross the sticky threshold, my element *never* sticks to the page.

I've never had issues using it before until now, so I'm not entirely sure why it's not working. I've also attempted various fixes for the flexbox (like specified in other posts), and also messing around with different heights and overflow values with no change.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="navigation" id="navigation">
    <div class="navigation-banner"></div>
    <div class="navigation-main"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#navigation{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-banner{
    color: #fff;
    background: #f17e0e;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.navigation-main{
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0px;

    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 18px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 4%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14amnpqh/) demo for your convenience.

Comment: add display:inline to #navigation

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some height in `#navigation` CSS, I just add `height: 800px` in `#navigation` CSS. I hope it'll resolve your issue. Thank You

```css
#navigation{
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-banner{
    color: #fff;
    background: #f17e0e;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.navigation-main{
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0px;

    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 18px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 4%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation" id="navigation">
    <div class="navigation-banner"></div>
    <div class="navigation-main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Also, why would I want my navigation to be 800px? xD

Comment: Hassan's solution does work, it's just that you can't see it properly as your navigation-main is white on a white background lol.. The only problem was that the '.navigation' container within which your sticky '.navigation-main' sits had no height.

Comment: @Marco I'm not thick lol; I know that it wasn't moving because I change the background colour when testing - and it very obviously has a `box-shadow` applied to it.